# Get files names in directory

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
Try
        For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("directory")
            FormMain.listbox.Items.Add(file)
        Next
    Catch 
    End Try
```

It will give me list of files in directory (like: C:\DIR\file.txt), but I need to get only files names (like: file.txt) - not names with addresses. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Take a look at the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  It has a number of useful methods in this area, one of which is specifically what you're looking for.

Comment: @JamesThorpe helped - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [FileInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Try
        For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("directory")
            Dim information = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file )
            FormMain.listbox.Items.Add(information.Name)
        Next
Catch 
End Try
```

Comment: This needs two trips to disk for each file.

Comment: Note that you could declare your for loop as such: `For Each file As System.IO.FileInfo In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("directory").GetFiles` and avoid the first line inside the loop above.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this as a one-liner for fun:

```
Try
    FormMain.listbox.Items.AddRange(New IO.DirectoryInfo("directory").EnumerateFiles().Select(Function(f) f.Name).ToArray())
Catch 
End Try
```

Also, I expect this to run roughly twice as fast as the current accepted answer, because it only needs to access your hard disk once for each file. The accetped  answer goes to the disk twice for each file. That said, this is unlikely to drive your program's performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("directory")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(file))
Next
```

Comment: This needs two trips to disk for each file.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The first disk access is GetFiles. What's the second one? I didn't think the Path class did any disk activity. It was just utility methods.

Comment: You are right. For some reason I was looking at that and reading it as new GetFileInfo().Name like the other answer.